# Missing value imputation with nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

Here I am trying to replace the Nan values with two different values 10050 and 10075, like the first Nan value with 10050 and second with 10075.

[image: Image preview]

Comment: Seen from the data that the column you want to process is a Flight Number which is a kind of identifier rather than continuous values.  So, you can still fill up the value as such ?   Moreover, how do you determine the value you want to fill up ?  It seems not a simple interpolation as the first value (10050) is not in the mid point (between 10045 and 10065, should it be 10055 instead ?) as the second one.   Suggest you can look at the pandas interpolation function [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) as a reference.

Comment: `df.loc[df['FilghtNumber'].isnull(), 'FilghtNumber'] = [10050, 10075]`, this is only available with two null to fill in.